# output error: #<LoadError: cannot load such file -- enc/trans/single_byte>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've reinstalled ruby with rbenv to version 2.4.2, after installation I want to run the rails console but every action I perform that uses any module defined in my code results in this error:

```
(pry) output error: #<LoadError: cannot load such file -- enc/trans/single_byte>
```

And a pretty long trace that is like this:

```
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/coderay-1.1.2/lib/coderay/scanners/scanner.rb:93:in `encode'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/coderay-1.1.2/lib/coderay/scanners/scanner.rb:93:in `encode_with_encoding'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/coderay-1.1.2/lib/coderay/scanners/scanner.rb:57:in `normalize'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/coderay-1.1.2/lib/coderay/scanners/scanner.rb:132:in `initialize'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/coderay-1.1.2/lib/coderay/encoders/encoder.rb:72:in `new'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/coderay-1.1.2/lib/coderay/encoders/encoder.rb:72:in `encode'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/coderay-1.1.2/lib/coderay.rb:197:in `encode'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/coderay-1.1.2/lib/coderay/tokens_proxy.rb:23:in `encode'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/coderay-1.1.2/lib/coderay/tokens_proxy.rb:32:in `method_missing'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/pry-0.11.0/lib/pry/color_printer.rb:29:in `text'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/pp.rb:315:in `pretty_print'
(...)
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
-e:1:in `<main>'
```

I've found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13400402/3663124 and yes, I have yml files with non ASCII chars, but they've never been a problem before.

Here's the rbenv install log:

```
$ rbenv install 2.4.2
ruby-build: use openssl from homebrew
Downloading ruby-2.4.2.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.4/ruby-2.4.2.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.4.2...
ruby-build: use readline from homebrew
Installed ruby-2.4.2 to /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem with ruby with rbenv to version 2.5.1. after reinstall ruby with rbenv to make readline to use libreadline.

```
(pry) output error: #<LoadError: cannot load such file -- enc/trans/single_byte>
```

It's stack trace

```
/Users/user-name/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/coderay-1.1.2/lib/coderay/scanners/scanner.rb:93:in `encode'
/Users/user-name/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/coderay-1.1.2/lib/coderay/scanners/scanner.rb:93:in `encode_with_encoding'
/Users/user-name/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/coderay-1.1.2/lib/coderay/scanners/scanner.rb:57:in `normalize'
/Users/user-name/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/coderay-1.1.2/lib/coderay/scanners/scanner.rb:132:in `initialize'
/Users/user-name/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/coderay-1.1.2/lib/coderay/encoders/encoder.rb:72:in `new'
/Users/user-name/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/coderay-1.1.2/lib/coderay/encoders/encoder.rb:72:in `encode'
```

In my case, to restart pc was the solution. Usually to reboot shell is the way to reflect changes, but I need to restart pc at that time.

Comment: I think that's what I ended up doing and for what I remembered it worked